# How to get url from AdView (AdMob)

Tags: android, url, hyperlink, admob, adview

As I know, AdView contains a link to playmarket or some site. I need to extract this link. Can I do this somehow?
Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: I would also like to know this.

Comment: Do you mean the URL it uses to get ads? Check logcat, admob produces quite a lot of info, you may find what you need there.

Comment: You need to create an account at admob-site ... once you done that you can genereate the id-string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its the same adView from AdMob. But if that is the case, you can create a custom ad class extending AdView and save the id of the add when you create and request your ad. That way, when you receive your Ad, you can use the id of it.

```
package core.globals.datatypes;

import android.app.Activity;

import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.doubleclick.DfpAdView;

public class CustomAd extends DfpAdView {

    String adUnitId;
    public CustomAd(Activity activity, AdSize adSize, String adUnitId) {
        super(activity, adSize, adUnitId);
        this.adUnitId = adUnitId;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public String getadUnitId() {
        return this.adUnitId;
    }
}
```